# Is it possible to do a redirect + POST from Chrome Extension

Tags: django, redirect, post, google-chrome-extension

If a user clicks on a link on my Chrome Extension, I would like them to be redirected to a page on my server, along with POST data (not GET data).

I followed the instructions here, http://theshybulb.com/2016/01/16/data-from-chromeextension-to-website.html, but Django is still recognizing it as a GET request, not a post request.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it turned out in my urls.py I had a trailing /, which caused everything to be redirected, thus, turning it into a GET request instead of a POST.